# How can I access environment variables from a file sitting inside the public folder in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, environment-variables, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating Firebase Cloud Messaging, and it is required to have `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file inside the public folder as a service worker.
The file needs to have my firebase config, which I of course want to hide the details of in environment veriables. I have the object defined as such:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
```

But now when I give permissions for notifications and it tries to register the service worker, I got the error: `caught ReferenceError: process is not defined`.
I have the variables defined in a `.env.local` file, and I've been using these same variables in my app in other places successfully.

How can I access them from a file in the public folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files in the public folder in nextjs don't go through the webpack build process hence why `process is undefined`.

To use environment variables in your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file, check the steps below.

First, create a `.env.local` file, skip this step if you already have it.

Install the `dotenv` package with `npm i dotenv`, will we use it to load the environment variables.

Create a file called `swEnvBuild.js` in the root directory.
In `swEnvBuild.js` file you just created, we will create a function that loads the `.env.local` file and then writes the contents of the file into a new file in the public folder called `swenv.js`

```
//swEnvBuild.js        
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.local' }); // make sure you have '.env.local' file.    
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync(
  './public/swenv.js',
  `
 const process = {
          env: {
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY}',
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN}',
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}',
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET}',
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}',
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID}',
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID}'
  }
 }`
);
```

Then we import the file that will be generated from `swEnvBuild.js` called `swenv.js` in the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file.

```
//firebase-messaging-sw.js    
importScripts('swenv.js'); // this file should have all the environment variables declared, allowing you to use process.env.ANY_KEY_YOU_DEFINED

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
```

Finally, update your package.json.

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "node swEnvBuild.js && next dev ",
        "build": "next build && node swEnvBuild.js",
 },
```

After running `npm run dev`, your environment variables should be accessible in `firebase-messaging-sw.js` using `process.env`

Comment: An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:4200/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at registerDefaultSw (index.esm2017.js:830:1)
    at async updateSwReg (index.esm2017.js:854:1)
    at async getToken$1 (index.esm2017.js:917:1)

Comment: Does this exact process work for React?

Comment: @Coolkid Yes, it works with Reactjs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to prefix your environment variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` in order for them to work in a file in the public directory.

As quoted from  [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser),

> In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the
> variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_

You don't access the process.env in your public file, rather you pass its value to the public file at build time as per the documentation example.

> The value will be inlined into JavaScript sent to the browser because
> of the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix. This inlining occurs at build time, so
> your various NEXT_PUBLIC_ envs need to be set when the project is
> built.

So, you import a setup function from your public folder file that sets the environment variables values at built time, on your public file code I assume you can name them whatever you like, you don't use `process.env` as the environment variables are of course not available for the browser.

So, then the significance of the prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` is just to be able to access the process env variables **values** in the Next react/typescript **client side code**, not in the public folder JavaScript files themselves, (the stress on the **values** of environment variables because you can't access actual web server process, **that's why dynamic lookups don't work as stated in the docs**)

> ```
> // This will NOT be inlined, because it uses a variable
> const varName = 'NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID'
> setupAnalyticsService(process.env[varName])
>
> // This will NOT be inlined, because it uses a variable
> const env = process.env
> setupAnalyticsService(env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID)
> ```

Comment: They already are prefixed as can be seen in the code I've provided.

Comment: @Tsabary where do you call your environment variables, do you only call them inside the public file itself, that won't work, you should import a setup function from your public file that will set the environment variables values to the public folder at build time in your home page, the env variables aren't passed to the public folder as is, but rather their values are passed as per the documentation I linked, continue reading the article