# Firebase Cloud Messaging: how do i get access to environment variables the public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, environment-variables, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm working on React and Firebase and i'm trying to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging. My main challenge is passing my app credentials to the `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. This file is in the public folder and can't access `.env` file. I've been looking at a number of tutorials and they cover FCM setup but not how to hide environment variables from public folder.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76057342/how-can-i-access-environment-variables-from-a-file-sitting-inside-the-public-fol) but for Next.js. I followed the instructions but didn't get the right outcome.

```
//firebase-messaging.sw.js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js");
// // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-messaging.js"
);
importScripts("swenv.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: payload.notification.image,
  };

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

How do i share my environment variables with my `firebase-messaging.sw.js` in the public folder?

Comment: I think the clue from the other question's answer is that "Files in the public folder in nextjs don't go through the webpack build process".  I don't think it's reasonable to expect environment variable substitution for anything in the public folder - those contents are likely just copied as-is to their final location.  All code that needs pre-processing should probably live elsewhere, perhaps alongside other source code.  You should consult React docs for how to integrate a service worker correctly.